# How to insert data in AbpUserLogins using abp framework

Tags: abp

I wanted to insert data in the AbpUserLogins table. I think we need to use Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityUserLogin.Please let me know how to insert data in the table.

I saw the below link,
A user is generally a person logins to and uses the application.

IdentityUser (aggregate root): Represents a user in the system.
IdentityUserRole (collection): Roles to the user.
IdentityUserClaim (collection): Custom claims of the user.
IdentityUserLogin (collection): External logins of the user.
IdentityUserToken (collection): Tokens of the user (used by the Microsoft Identity services).

Thanks.